# How to add new row in R Shiny dataTable without refreshing the existing selected data variable in table

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server, shinyapps

I am trying to create a data filter using R Shiny and DataTables, So far I am able to add the data and when I click on Add New Filter after selecting the variables , The selected variable values is refreshed.

Please help me so when I add new row , the selected variable remains same.

Below is the code:

server.r

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)
library(shinyjs)
library(DT)
library(rhandsontable)



shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  myValue <- reactiveValues()
  
  observe({
    if(is.null(myValue$Filter)){
      Choices<- c("a","b","c","d")
      myValue$Filter  = data.frame(
        Variable = shinyInput(selectInput, 1:5, 'var_', cl = "dynamicInputs", label = "", choices = Choices ,selected=Choices[1]),
        Filter = shinyInput(actionButton,  1:5, 'go_button_', cl=NULL, label = "Filter", onclick = goButtonOnClick()) ,
        Logic = c(NA,shinyInput(selectInput, 2:5, 'logic_', cl = "dynamicInputs",label = "", choices = c("And","Or"))),
        Remove = c(NA,shinyInput(actionButton, 2:5, 'remove_button_',cl=NULL, "", icon = icon("close"), onclick = removeButtonOnClick())),
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
        row.names = 1:5
      )

      maxId<<-5
    }
  })
  

  #Functions 
  shinyInput <- function(FUN, objs, id,cl= NULL, ...) {
    inputs <- character(length(objs))
    if(is.null(cl)){
      for (i in 1:length(objs)) {
        inputs[i] <- as.character(FUN(paste0(id, objs[i]), ...))
      }
    }
    else {
      for (i in 1:length(objs)) {
        inputs[i] <- as.character(div(class=cl,FUN(paste0(id, objs[i]), ...)))
      }
    }
    inputs
  }
  
  
  goButtonOnClick <- function() {
    return('Shiny.onInputChange(\"select_button\",  this.id) ; 
                Shiny.setInputValue(\"filter_button_change\", Math.random()) ')
  }
  
  
  removeButtonOnClick <- function() {
    return('Shiny.onInputChange(\"select_remove_button\",  this.id)')
  }
  
  
  
  extractValues<-function(idSeq,objName){
    unlist(lapply(idSeq,function(id){
      selected<-as.numeric(id)
      return(as.character(shinyValue(objName, selected)))
    }))
  }
  
  
  # Add new Condition Row 
  observeEvent(input$addnewRow,{
    
    if(is.null(myValue$Filter) || nrow(myValue$Filter)==0)
      return()
    
    idSeq<-unlist(lapply(myValue$Filter$Filter,function(x){
      buttonId<-stringr::str_extract(x,paste0("go_button_","\\d+"))
      num<-as.numeric(gsub("go_button_","",buttonId))
      return(num)
    }))
    
    
    allVars<-extractValues(idSeq,"var_")
    allLogic<-extractValues(idSeq,"logic_")
    
    Choices<- c("a","b","c","d")
   
    
    
    Variable<-unlist(lapply(1:length(idSeq),function(i){
      shinyInput(selectInput, idSeq[i], 'var_', cl = "dynamicInputs", label = "", choices = Choices ,selected=allVars[i])
    }))
    
    Logic<-unlist(lapply(1:length(idSeq),function(i){
      if(is.na(allLogic[i]))
        return(NA)
      shinyInput(selectInput, idSeq[i], 'logic_', cl = "dynamicInputs",label = "", choices = c("And","Or"),selected=allLogic[i])
    }))
    
   
    myValue$Filter$Variable<-Variable
    myValue$Filter$Logic<-Logic
    
    maxId<<-maxId+1   
    
    newRow <- data.frame(
      Variable = shinyInput(selectInput, maxId, 'var_', cl = "dynamicInputs", label = "", choices = Choices),
      Filter = shinyInput(actionButton, maxId, 'go_button_',cl=NULL, label = "Filter", onclick = goButtonOnClick() ),
      Logic = shinyInput(selectInput, maxId, 'logic_',cl = "dynamicInputs", label = "", choices = c("And","Or")),
      Remove = shinyInput(actionButton, maxId, 'remove_button_',cl=NULL,  "", icon = icon("close"), onclick = removeButtonOnClick() ),
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    )
    rownames(newRow) <- as.character(nrow(myValue$Filter)+1)

    myValue$Filter <- rbind(myValue$Filter,newRow)
  })
  
  # Remove Row 
  observeEvent(input$select_remove_button,{
    if(is.null(myValue$Filter) || nrow(myValue$Filter)==0)
      return()
    
    idSeq<-unlist(lapply(myValue$Filter$Filter,function(x){
      buttonId<-stringr::str_extract(x,paste0("go_button_","\\d+"))
      num<-as.numeric(gsub("go_button_","",buttonId))
      return(num)
    }))
    
    allVars<-extractValues(idSeq,"var_")
    allLogic<-extractValues(idSeq,"logic_")
    
    Choices <- c("a","b","c","d")
    
    Variable<-unlist(lapply(1:length(idSeq),function(i){
      shinyInput(selectInput, idSeq[i], 'var_', cl = "dynamicInputs", label = "", choices = Choices ,selected=allVars[i])
    }))
    
    Logic<-unlist(lapply(1:length(idSeq),function(i){
      if(is.na(allLogic[i]))
        return(NA)
      shinyInput(selectInput, idSeq[i], 'logic_', cl = "dynamicInputs",label = "", choices = c("And","Or"),selected=allLogic[i])
    }))
    
    myValue$Filter$Variable<-Variable
    myValue$Filter$Logic<-Logic
    
    rowToRemove<- which(unlist(lapply(myValue$Filter$Remove,function(x){stringr::str_extract(x,paste0("remove_button_","\\d+"))}))==input$select_remove_button)
    myValue$Filter<-myValue$Filter[-rowToRemove,]
    
    if(nrow(myValue$Filter)>0)  
      rownames(myValue$Filter)<-as.character(1:nrow(myValue$Filter))
  })
  
  # Display bsModal for filter 
  observeEvent(input$filter_button_change, {
    toggleModal(session,"CustomDataFilter",toggle="open")
  })
  
  
  
  
  
  # helper function for reading selectinput
  shinyValue = function(id, objs) {
    
    unlist(lapply(objs, function(i) {
      value = input[[paste0(id, i)]]
      if (is.null(value))
        NA
      else{
      
        value
      }
    }))
  }
  
  # Show Filter Table
  output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({
    if(is.null(myValue$Filter))
      return()
   
    myValue$Filter
    
  }, selection = 'none', server = FALSE, escape = FALSE, options = list(
    dom = "ti",
    paging = TRUE,
    preDrawCallback = JS(
      'function() {
      Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'
    ),
    drawCallback = JS('function() {
                      Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); } ')
  ))
  
  

  
  
})
```

ui.r

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)
library(shinyjs)
library(DT)
library(rhandsontable)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  
  tags$head(tags$script(HTML("
                            $(document).on('change', '.dynamicInputs .selector select', function(){
                                       Shiny.setInputValue('lastSelectId', this.id, {priority: 'event'});
                                       });
                                      
                                      
                                       "))),  
  
  tags$script(
    HTML(
      "Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('unbind-DT', function(id) {
        Shiny.unbindAll($('#'+id).find('table').DataTable().table().node());
        })"
    )
  ),
  
  
  
  tags$button(
    id = "reset_button",
    class="btn action-button",
    icon("close")
  ),
  
  
  bsModal("CustomDataFilter","Settings","go_CustomDataFilter_Settings",size="large",
          uiOutput("FilterDataSettings")
          
          
          
  ), 
  
  bsModal("CustomDataFormula","Settings","go_CustomDataFormula_Settings",size="large",
          uiOutput("CustomDataFormula")
          
          
          
  ),
  
  actionButton("addnewRow"," Add New Filter "),
  DT::dataTableOutput('mytable')
  
  
)



)
```

Comment: I don't see any data, only a table where you can add/remove filters. Can you please specify how to reproduce your error.

Comment: As there is no data being read in, it is not clear what you are expecting. At the moment, it is retaining the value of the selected variables, if other variables are deleted or added. Once you select a variable, do you plan to select a single or multiple values of the available content in the dataframe for that variable? I presume that and/or is for the next variable to be subset.

Comment: In order to reproduce the issue , select the variables from the select dropdown for all the variables and click on Add new Row this resets the selected value in the dropdown which is the problem, I do not want the values to reset.

Comment: In short, what I am expecting is that after adding 2-3 new rows it should not reset the pre selected values in the drop-down.

Comment: @PawanRamaMali, The issue is that you are resetting all `selectInputs` in the `observeEvent(input$addnewRow,{…}`. You should just add one more `selectinput` item for the new filter.  If you just change the choices list in each location, you will see that every time you add or remove a filter variable you are resetting the `selectInput`.   Same is true in the other observe event where you remove.